# Laravel: print URL or default value in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have Post model which has user function returning User model - creator of the post.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get the user that owns the post.
    */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

In blade view I achieved how to print author name

```
{{ $post->user->name or 'Anonymous' }}
```

Above code works, but it is very hmm sensitive?
For example, I tried change this code to:

```
{{ $post->user->name, 'Anonymous' }}

<?php $post->user->name or 'Anonymous' ?>
```

Results? **Trying to get property of non-object** error on line with this code.
Maybe I am skipping something simple but important. How to print URL or default value in blade view. Pseudo code what I mean:

```
{{ '<a href="url('/profile/' .$post->user->name)"></a>' or 'Anonymous' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{{ isset($post->user->name) ? '<a href="url('/profile/' . $post->user->name)"></a>' : 'Anonymous' }}
```

If this doesn't work (I haven't check it) try something like this:

```
@if (isset($post->user->name))
     <a href="url('/profile/' . $post->user->name)"></a>
@else
     Anonymous
@endif
```

Comment: First code throws "Use of undefined constant profile - assumed 'profile'" error when condition is true, and Anonymous when condition is false. Second code throws plain variable names when condition is true, and Anonymous when condition is false. `<a href="{{ url('/profile/' .$post->user->name) }}">{{ $post->user->name }}</a>` fixes it

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error is not because the code is sensitive, it is because you are actually trying to access non objects values.

To achieve what you are looking for:

```
{{ isset($post->user)?'<a href="url('/profile/' .$post->user->name)"></a>' : 'Anonymous' }}
```